# How do i get dismiss modal view controller to happen first?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have this code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

...

}
```

Unfortunately, it runs the rest of the code (which can take a few seconds) before dismissing the modal view controller. How can i make it dismiss it first, and then run the rest of the code?

Comment: lol. just set animation to NO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't dismiss the modal view controller or do any other UI updates until it gets back to the main run loop (i.e. the function returns).

If you have a task that is going to take a noticeable amount of time to complete, you should perform it on a background thread instead of on the main thread. The usual thing is to use [`performSelectorInBackground:withObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-SW4); but do remember that any UI updates (e.g. when the operation is complete) must be done on the main thread, so your background method may have to use [`performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-CJBEHAEF).

If you prefer blocks, you could use [`dispatch_async`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_async) instead:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
    // background operation
});
```

If you have a number of background operations, you could also look into [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html) for the background operation.

Comment: So you're suggesting i make a separate method with all my code in that was previously summed up with the '...'. Then i replace it with the line `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(newMethod)WithObject:object];`, and then on the part of the separate method that I want to make UI changes, i put it in another method, and then put the line `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(anotherMethod)....];`?

Comment: @Andrew: Yes. Or you can use blocks (which may be more straightforward of a change), or an NSOperationQueue.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need the animation, try:

```
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Comment: Please change your answer to NO.