# Progress bar not updating as often as it should be

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have this code:

```
UIImage *resizedImage = [MediaSource resizeImage:image];
    progressBar.progress = 0.2;
    NSString *filePath = [MediaSource writeImageToFile:resizedImage];
    progressBar.progress = 0.5;
    NSString *fullImagePath = [MediaSource writeImageToFile:image];
    progressBar.progress = 0.8;
    UIImage *thumbnail = [MediaSource createThumbnailForMediaType:@"Image" WithImage:image];
    progressBar.progress = 0.9;
    NSString *thumbnailPath = [MediaSource writeImageToFile:thumbnail];
    progressBar.progress = 1.0;
```

Despite writeImageToFile taking a second or more, the progress bar is never updated with the values in the middle, only given 0.2 and then finally 1.0. How can i make it show all the values as it gets to them?

EDIT: Commenting out the first progress update leaves it at 0. Not sure why this is going wrong.

Comment: My hunch is that the program is not refreshing the screen often enough. One way might be to call a repaint function of some sort each time, though I have no idea what framework you're using so I can't confirm that one exists.

Comment: This is still the same problem you were having [earlier today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985090/how-do-i-get-dismiss-modal-view-controller-to-happen-first). You can't update the GUI continuously inside a method; you have to let the current [run loop](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/MainEventLoop.html) end in order for things to get displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

You should put some of that code into a background thread and notify of progress changes the main thread that drives the UI.

Here you're not giving the runloop any chance to run around at least once, so it's likely that the main thread, being busy with writing the file, doesn't have time to update the progress bar more than once maybe.

Separate the steps into a series of `NSOperation`s driven by an `NSOperationQueue` for example. This will give the user a much smoother experience.

Answer (score 1):

For the progress bar to update properly you need to perform your long running operations on a background thread and your progress updates on the main thread. That means use an async dispatch queue or [detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSThread/detachNewThreadSelector%3atoTarget%3awithObject%3a) and then post back to the main thread any progress.